# convert php array to javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

***This question is no longer relevant. I can not delete this question as others invested their time and effort. I ask everyone who commented here to delete their comments, so it is possible I can delete this question for the junk-free stackoverflow***

**My prevoius question changed **

My prevoius code in php

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2000
                [title] => TIERE, DIANA
            )
        [1]  => Array
            (
               [id] => 1500
               [title] =>fhg , DIANA 
            )
    )
```

and in javascript , JSON.parse(obj) woked fine and it gives me an array of object
like

```
  [
    0:object
    1:object
  ]
```

then i changed my php array to

```
 Array
    (
        [2000] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2000
                [title] => TIERE, DIANA
            )
        [1500]  => Array
            (
               [id] => 1500
               [title] =>fhg , DIANA 
            )
    )
```

but  JSON.parse(obj) gives only one object in array lie as follows

```
[object]
```

My question is how to build json array in javascrip like as follows

```
   [
    2000: Object
    1500: Object
    800: Object
    500: Object
   ]
```

from a php array like this

```
Array
(
    [2000] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2000
            [title] => TIERE, DIANA
        )
    [1500]  => Array
        (
           [id] => 1500
           [title] =>fhg , DIANA 
        )
)
```

Comment: Please be more _specific_.

Comment: have you tried inspecting the element with your browser inspector first?

Comment: @MaxHartshorn please check the quest now. ad let me know if you still have doubt..

Comment: Can you get rid of absolute positioning, and use floats or inline-blocks instead? Then it would just work by itself.

Comment: Actualy it is a custom map of a road. so for other calculation i need left with some percentage value.

Comment: @undefined please vote up..i have clarified it

Comment: @MaxHartshorn please vote up.i have clarified it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can probably find a better solution than what you're trying to do using CSS, but I think this is what you're asking for:

```
var positions = new Array();
$('.icon').each(function() {
  var $icon = $(this);
  var left = $icon.css('left');
  if ($.inArray(left, positions)) {
    // yes, an icon already exists with this CSS left value.
    // I'm not sure what you intended to do about it.
    // maybe increment the alignment of this one?
    left = left + 2;
    $icon.css('left', left);
  }
  positions.push(left);
});
```

Comment: yes this is what am looking for.

Comment: i have upaded the question